# Passing args with space in Atom's .atom-build.yml

Tags: makefile, cmake, yaml, atom-editor

[Atom Build package](https://atom.io/packages/build) uses `.atom-build.yml` file to specify project build targets, so I created simple `.atom-build.yml` to suit my needs. Everything works fine, except one small part. Below its context:

```
targets:
    Run CMake for Windows:
        cmd: "cmake"
        atomCommandName: "Create Makefiles with CMake"
        args:
            - "-Bbuild"
            - "-H."
            - "-G\"MinGW Makefiles\""
```

In this particular target I'd like to envoke `cmake`, as [Build CMake](https://atom.io/packages/build-cmake) is not working, or I have no idea how to use it. When used, Build package runs `cmd /C` to run command written after `cmd:` with arguments `args:`. Thus, call shown in Atom is:

```
cmd /C cmake -Bbuild -H. -G"MinGW Makefiles"
```

With `-G` option I define target `make` enviroment, which is `NMake Makefiles` by default and I'd like to have `MinGW Makefiles`. After running target above, `cmake` throws error:

```
CMake Error: Could not create named generator "MinGW
```

... and lists all available generators. Clearly, space in `MinGW Makefiles` makes `Makefiles` being understood as next argument. I tried escaping it with `\` and `^`, but it's not working. Also, I tried moving args to `cmd` field, as it would run from single command line call.

**My question is:** how to run `cmake` target as above using Atom Build package with `-G` option passed to `cmake` properly?

---

**EDIT:**

With `'-G "MinGW Makefiles"'` error persists.

With `"-G ""MinGW Makefiles"""` Atom throws error:

```
bad indentation of a sequence entry at line 15, column 19:
                - "-G""MinGW Makefiles"""
                      ^
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the space, e.g. `"-G\"MinGW\ Makefiles\""`

Comment: As i mentioned: "I tried escaping it with \ and ^, but it's not working."

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package, but it's possible that it's removing quotes from the string before passing it to the shell.

Comment: I don't think so. Check call shown in Atom and CMake error - both have quotes.

Comment: Have you tried `"-G ""MinGW Makefiles"""`?

Comment: Have you tried using a combination of single and double quotes? `'-G "MinGW Makefiles"'`?

Comment: Updated question in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across your post when I searched a solution for a similar problem. I was trying to add the makefile targets as commands. After many trails, finally I got it working.

```
cmd: "C:/WinAVR-20100110/utils/bin/make.exe all"
name: all

errorMatch:
  - (?<file>[0-9a-zA-Z_]+\\.+[cC]):(?<line>\\d+):\\s+(?<message>.+)
targets:
    build all:
        cmd: "C:/WinAVR-20100110/utils/bin/make.exe all"
    clean and rebuild:
        cmd: "C:/WinAVR-20100110/utils/bin/make.exe rebuild"
    clear artifacts:
        cmd: "C:/WinAVR-20100110/utils/bin/make.exe clean"
```

The idea here is to pass the arguments as part of command itself not as a separate argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found other way to run `cmake` with parameters as above. I created `PreLoad.cmake` file, consisting:

```
set (CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set (CMAKE_GENERATOR "MinGW Makefiles" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "build" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

This file is envoked by `cmake` before CMakeLists.txt, so it overrides default `cmake` settings. Secondly, I modified `.atom-build.yml`:

```
cmd: "g++"
atomCommandName: "Compile and run with g++"
name: "Compile and run single file C++ project"
args:
    - "{FILE_ACTIVE}"
    - "-o {FILE_ACTIVE_PATH}/application.exe &&"
    - "{FILE_ACTIVE_PATH}/application.exe"
targets:
    Run CMake:
        cmd: "cmake ."
        atomCommandName: "Create Makefiles with CMake"
    Build Makefile project:
        atomCommandName: "Make all"
        cmd: "make"
        args:
            - "-j4"
            - "all"
    Run application:
        atomCommandName: "Run application"
        cmd: "{FILE_ACTIVE_PATH}/build/application.exe"
    Full CMake build:
        atomCommandName: "Full CMake build"
        cmd: "cmake . && make -j4 all && {FILE_ACTIVE_PATH}/build/application.exe"
```

Works *almost* perfect - Atom Build package does not support input.

---

Running:

```
cmd /C cmake -Bbuild -H. -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=make
```

directly from command prompt (or without `cmd /C`), works. Yet from Atom I get:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

which is `cmd` error. I have no idea why it persists.